# Having trouble getting a PHP class function to use another function in the class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

In my PHP file, I have a class with all of my functions, and I am using this class to interact with another file. Here's the code I am using:

```
    public function check_user_exists ($username_original) {
    try {
        $db_connect = SQLConnect(); // Make the PDO handle usable

        // Prepare and fetch the id of the user trying to login, used to validate whether the user exists or not
        $db_interact = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username_raw` = :username_raw");
        $db_interact->bindParam(":username_raw", $username_original);
        $db_interact->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $db_interact->execute();
        $db_fetch = $db_interact->fetch();

        if ($db_fetch == false) {    
            return false;
        } else {
            global $validation_code;
            $validation_code = $db_fetch["id"];// Used to log the id of the use0r logging in
            return true;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage; // Used if something goes wrong with the PDO statement
    }
}
```

This is a simple function using PDO to check if a user exists in the database.

As you can see in the third line of code, the function references `SQLConnect()`. When I use the function `check_user_exists()`, it gives me a fatal error, saying that I made a call to an undefined function, except `SQLConnect()` is in the same file, and the same PHP class.

This is `SQLConnect()`:

```
    // Function to allow database interactions
public function SQLConnect () {
    // Database connection variables
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "dropbox-database";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "password";
    // Set connect to null
    static $connect = null;

    if (is_null($connect)) {
        try {
            // Database connection variables
            $host = "localhost";
            $dbname = "dropbox-database";
            $user = "root";
            $password = "ethan17458";
            // Initiate connection
            $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
            // Set error mode
            $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // If there is an error, echo error message
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        // Make $connect usable
        return $connect;
    }
}
```

I'm using this function to open a database connection using PDO.

Why would this trigger a fatal error when both functions are in the same file, and in the same class? How would I fix this problem?

Thanks,

Ethan

Comment: because a function in a class is a method of the class as opposed to a globally accessible function. You would access it as $this->SQLConnect()

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db_connect = SQLConnect();
```

should be

```
$db_connect = $this->SQLConnect();
```

because functions within a class are methods of the class and not globally accessible. Using $this-> is telling PHP to locate the method within the class. It should be noted `$this` means much more but this is a succinct fix for your immediate problem.